# Efficiently: sum non-diagonal elements, by axis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix, and then I need to sum over some axis, ignoring diagonal elements. What would be an efficient approach for this?

For example, take

```
>>> transitionE
array([[ 0.883,  0.117,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.045,  0.868,  0.087,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.063,  0.874,  0.063,  0.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.087,  0.868,  0.045],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.117,  0.883]])
```

What I am doing for now is

```
>>> transitionE.sum(axis=1) - transitionE.diagonal()
array([ 0.117,  0.132,  0.126,  0.132,  0.117])
```

You cannot rely on the `0`s in some of the cells. Is there a more efficient way to do this operation?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a bit? Why does it matter that some cells contain `0`? The solution you've proposed — `arr.sum(axis=n) - arr.diagonal()` — seems correct from what you've described.

Comment: @DavidWolever sorry, it doesn't. I meant: "Here in this example, some cells contain 0. In others, they might not. Please do not rely on the fact that there are some 0s here". Yeah, the solution works, I'm just wondering whether there is something more efficient.

Comment: and my apologies — I hit enter too quickly and didn't finish the comment. What is the issue with your proposed solution? It seems both correct and efficient.

Comment: On a whim I tried using a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) and it was about 3 times slower than your solution.  Your approach is plenty efficient.

Comment: @roippi Im not sure how to proceed. You could answer that and I'd accept, or I could just delete this altogether. (How to know whether a better approach exists or not?)